# App stops working when Screen turns off

Tags: android, android-resources

I have created and android app which works in `Landscape` orientation mode. It keeps the screen on when it is active. However, when I lock the screen using the power button and the app is on, it stops working and gives the `Resources$NotFoundException` in `LogCat`, pointing to the `onCreate()` method of the Activity. Please help.

**MenuActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu); // Error points here
    bjmc.activity = this;
    preference = getSharedPreferences("BJLocalPlayer", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (!preference.contains("balance") || (preference.getLong("balance", 0)) < 100) {
        Editor edit = preference.edit();
        edit.putLong("balance", 1000);
        edit.commit();
    }
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.player_balance)).setText(Long
            .toString(preference.getLong("balance", 0)));

    tvAmerican = new TextView(this);
    tvAmerican.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    tvAmerican.setBackgroundColor(0x40000000);
    tvAmerican.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.orangish_yellow));
    tvAmerican.setText("American");
    tvEuropean = new TextView(this);
    tvEuropean.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    tvEuropean.setText("European");

    final TabHost th = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.table_tab_host);
    th.setup();
    th.addTab(th.newTabSpec("American").setIndicator(tvAmerican)
            .setContent(R.id.american));
    th.addTab(th.newTabSpec("European").setIndicator(tvEuropean)
            .setContent(R.id.european));
    th.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (tabId) {
            case "American":
                tvAmerican.setBackgroundColor(0x40000000);
                tvAmerican.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.orangish_yellow));
                tvEuropean.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
                tvEuropean.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.total_text_color));
                break;
            case "European":
                tvAmerican.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
                tvAmerican.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.total_text_color));
                tvEuropean.setBackgroundColor(0x40000000);
                tvEuropean.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.orangish_yellow));
                break;
            }
        }
    });
    final ViewPager american = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.american);
    american.setAdapter(new ImagePagerAdapter(getLayoutInflater(),
            new int[] { R.drawable.am_table0, R.drawable.am_table1,
                    R.drawable.am_table2, R.drawable.am_table3,
                    R.drawable.am_table4 }));
    final ViewPager european = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.european);
    european.setAdapter(new ImagePagerAdapter(getLayoutInflater(),
            new int[] { R.drawable.eu_table0, R.drawable.eu_table1,
                    R.drawable.eu_table2, R.drawable.eu_table3,
                    R.drawable.eu_table4 }));

    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button_play_single_player)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    tableIndex = (th.getCurrentTab() == 0 ? american.getCurrentItem()
                            : european.getCurrentItem() + 5);
                    bjmc.startGameForTableIndex(tableIndex,
                        BJMatchCoordinator.SINGLEPLAYER, new BJMCDelegate(MenuActivity.this));
                }
            });

    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button_play_bluetooth)).setOnClickListener(new BluetoothListener());
}
```

**UPDATE**

**LogCat**

```
07-14 11:50:18.129: W/ResourceType(4091): Failure getting entry for 0x7f030018 (t=2 e=24) in package 0 (error -75)
07-14 11:50:18.179: W/dalvikvm(4091): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40af39f0)
07-14 11:50:18.219: E/AndroidRuntime(4091): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-14 11:50:18.219: E/AndroidRuntime(4091): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.iapp.bjp/com.iapp.bjp.MenuActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030018
07-14 11:50:18.219: E/AndroidRuntime(4091):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
07-14 11:50:18.219: E/AndroidRuntime(4091):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
07-14 11:50:18.219: E/AndroidRuntime(4091):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3351)
07-14 11:50:18.219: E/AndroidRuntime(4091):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:123)
07-14 11:50:18.219: E/AndroidRuntime(4091):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1151)
07-14 11:50:18.219: E/AndroidRuntime(4091):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-14 11:50:18.219: E/AndroidRuntime(4091):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-14 11:50:18.219: E/AndroidRuntime(4091):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-14 11:50:18.219: E/AndroidRuntime(4091):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-14 11:50:18.219: E/AndroidRuntime(4091):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-14 11:50:18.219: E/AndroidRuntime(4091):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
07-14 11:50:18.219: E/AndroidRuntime(4091):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
07-14 11:50:18.219: E/AndroidRuntime(4091):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-14 11:50:18.219: E/AndroidRuntime(4091): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030018
07-14 11:50:18.219: E/AndroidRuntime(4091):     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1022)
07-14 11:50:18.219: E/AndroidRuntime(4091):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2109)
07-14 11:50:18.219: E/AndroidRuntime(4091):     at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:861)
07-14 11:50:18.219: E/AndroidRuntime(4091):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
07-14 11:50:18.219: E/AndroidRuntime(4091):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
07-14 11:50:18.219: E/AndroidRuntime(4091):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:268)
07-14 11:50:18.219: E/AndroidRuntime(4091):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1837)
07-14 11:50:18.219: E/AndroidRuntime(4091):     at com.iapp.bjp.MenuActivity.onCreate(MenuActivity.java:55)
07-14 11:50:18.219: E/AndroidRuntime(4091):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
07-14 11:50:18.219: E/AndroidRuntime(4091):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
07-14 11:50:18.219: E/AndroidRuntime(4091):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
07-14 11:50:18.219: E/AndroidRuntime(4091):     ... 12 more
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.iapp.bjp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.iapp.bjp.MenuActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.iapp.bjp.SinglePlayerAddBetActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_single_player_add_bet"
            android:parentActivityName="com.iapp.bjp.MenuActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.iapp.bjp.MenuActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.iapp.bjp.SinglePlayerGameActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_single_player_game"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.iapp.bjp.bluetooth.ScanDeviceActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_scan_device" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**UPDATE 2**

**activity_menu.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/menu_background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_menu"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    tools:context="com.iapp.bjp.MenuActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/player_balance_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/player_balance_text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/player_balance"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TabHost
        android:id="@+id/table_tab_host"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="2" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.TextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/american"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/european"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_play_single_player"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/home_btn_ph"
            android:text="@string/single_play_button_text" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_play_bluetooth"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/home_btn_ph"
            android:text="@string/bluetooth_button_text" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Note:** Please keep in mind that the app works fine on normal usage. The problem occurs when I turn the screen off using the power button.

Comment: post logcat+ your manifest file

Comment: How do I post LogCat properly? I have saved the log to a text file but copying and pasting it here removes all the formatting. Even indenting with tabs does not help.

Comment: @SMR I have updated with the Logcat output and Manifest file.

Comment: @Anil I have updated with the Logcat output and Manifest file.

Comment: indicate line 55 @ `MenuActivity`

Comment: @shayan I have. Its the `setContentView()` line with the comment `Error points here`

Comment: post `activity_menu` layout file

Comment: If you're not getting any warnings in your IDE, you may just need to clean and rebuild the project.

Comment: @shayan updated with `activity_menu`

Comment: try change `@android:id` to `@+id` in your xml layout

Comment: @MikeM. Tried it. No difference :(

Comment: @shayan It gives errors "your tabhost must have a tabwidget with id android.R.id.tabs" and "your tabhost must have a framelayout with id android.R.id.tabcontent"

Comment: @MikeM. If that were the case, the app should not have run in the first place, like id did with the other two cases. As I said, it runs fine when I operate it normally. It only misbehaves when I lock the screen off.

Comment: Yeah, I just saw that.

Comment: @MikeM. Tried your suggestion anyways. No difference.

Comment: @MikeM. My layouts were in the layout-land folder, that's why it could not find them. Thank you for your time :)

Comment: @shayan My layouts were in the layout-land folder, hence the error. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had kept the layout xml files in the `layout-land` folder instead of the `layout` folder. When I locked the screen, it turned to portrait mode internally (don't know why it always stays in that orientation though) and as it could not find resources for portrait mode, it gave the `Resources$NotFoundException`

Answer (score 1):

Remove "android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"" from your manifest and also post your activity_menu.xml

Comment: I added `activity_menu`. If I remove `sensorLandscape`, how do I keep the app in `Landscape` orientation?

Comment: I had my resources in layout-land folder, that's why it could not find them. Thank you for your time :)